# How to Escape @ (At the rate) from url using urlrewrite.xml in java

Tags: java, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I have an URL look like this

```
site/story/one-direction-makes-billboard-@ashutosh-singh-history-knocks-swift-from-no.-1/1/403939.html
```

Here I want to escape @ from URL using urlrewrite.xml. How can I do it?
Does anyone know, please suggest.

I have tried something like this

```
<rule match-type="regex" enabled="true">    
<from>/story/(([a-z-]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/$)\.html</from>
<to type="permanent-redirect">/story/$1/$2/$3</to>   
</rule>
```

But this is not working and I required URL in this format

```
site/story/one-direction-makes-billboard-ashutosh-singh-history-knocks-swift-from-no.-1/1/403939.html
```

Comment: Try adding @ to [a-z-] e.g. [a-z\-@] I think you need to escape - (hyphen) as well

Comment: I have required hyphen (-) in my url, it's mandatory. Let me try which you have told me and will update here accordingly.

Comment: hyphen is used as range separator as in a-z, hence the hyphen after it should be escaped. but if it works un-escaped then keep it as is.

Comment: Hi Sameer, the above solution is not working for me. The solution did not escape @ from url.

Comment: I don't have a working setup of this filter. so guessing that this regexp might work for you. /story/(.*)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)\.html You might have to use a non-greedy qualifier after + if first [0-9] matches all digits, as in [0-9]+? where ? is non-greedy match in perl. Check if its the same for tuckey filter.